# Failed to load template: while serving build app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, http-status-code-404

So I'm getting a `404 error` in serving my build app. In the development its not throwing any error so i'm kinda lost on how to solve this. Been tackling this error for days now and i can really use some help.

And my question is that why is it still calling the `/app/dashboard/dashboard.html` even though its already compress to a build state ?

I used **hottowel** to create the project. I used `gulp build` to build the app and **gulp serve-build** to serve the app.

**Output Error in Browser Console**

[image]

**dashboard route**

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.dashboard')
    .run(appRun);

  appRun.$inject = ['routerHelper'];
  /* @ngInject */
  function appRun(routerHelper) {
    routerHelper.configureStates(getStates());
  }

  function getStates() {
    return [
      {
        state: 'dashboard',
        config: {
          url: '/dashboard',
          templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
          controller: 'DashboardController',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
          title: 'Admin Dashboard',
          authenticated: true,
          permissions: 'admin',
          settings: {
            nav: 2,
            content: '<i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard'
          }
        }
      }
    ];
  }
})();
```

**gulp.js**

```js
var args = require('yargs').argv;
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var config = require('./gulp.config')();
var del = require('del');
var glob = require('glob');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var path = require('path');
var _ = require('lodash');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({ lazy: true });

var colors = $.util.colors;
var envenv = $.util.env;
var port = process.env.PORT || config.defaultPort;

/**
 * yargs variables can be passed in to alter the behavior, when present.
 * Example: gulp serve-dev
 *
 * --verbose  : Various tasks will produce more output to the console.
 * --nosync   : Don't launch the browser with browser-sync when serving code.
 * --debug    : Launch debugger with node-inspector.
 * --debug-brk: Launch debugger and break on 1st line with node-inspector.
 * --startServers: Will start servers for midway tests on the test task.
 */

/**
 * List the available gulp tasks
 */
gulp.task('help', $.taskListing);
gulp.task('default', ['help']);

/**
 * vet the code and create coverage report
 * @return {Stream}
 */
gulp.task('vet', function () {
  log('Analyzing source with JSHint and JSCS');

  return gulp
    .src(config.alljs)
    .pipe($.if(args.verbose, $.print()))
    .pipe($.jshint())
    .pipe($.jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish', { verbose: true }))
    .pipe($.jshint.reporter('fail'))
    .pipe($.jscs());
});

/**
 * Create a visualizer report
 */
gulp.task('plato', function (done) {
  log('Analyzing source with Plato');
  log('Browse to /report/plato/index.html to see Plato results');

  startPlatoVisualizer(done);
});

/**
 * Compile less to css
 * @return {Stream}
 */
gulp.task('styles', ['clean-styles'], function () {
  log('Compiling Less --> CSS');

  return gulp
    .src(config.less)
    .pipe($.plumber()) // exit gracefully if something fails after this
    .pipe($.less())
    //        .on('error', errorLogger) // more verbose and dupe output. requires emit.
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 version', '> 5%'] }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.temp));
});

/**
 * Copy fonts
 * @return {Stream}
 */
gulp.task('fonts', ['clean-fonts'], function () {
  log('Copying fonts');

  return gulp
    .src(config.fonts)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build + 'fonts'));
});

/**
 * Compress images
 * @return {Stream}
 */
gulp.task('images', ['clean-images'], function () {
  log('Compressing and copying images');

  return gulp
    .src(config.images)
    .pipe($.imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 4 }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build + 'images'));
});

gulp.task('less-watcher', function () {
  gulp.watch([config.less], ['styles']);
});

/**
 * Create $templateCache from the html templates
 * @return {Stream}
 */
gulp.task('templatecache', ['clean-code'], function () {
  log('Creating an AngularJS $templateCache');

  return gulp
    .src(config.htmltemplates)
    .pipe($.if(args.verbose, $.bytediff.start()))
    .pipe($.minifyHtml({ empty: true }))
    .pipe($.if(args.verbose, $.bytediff.stop(bytediffFormatter)))
    .pipe($.angularTemplatecache(
      config.templateCache.file,
      config.templateCache.options
    ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.temp));
});

/**
 * Wire-up the bower dependencies
 * @return {Stream}
 */
gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
  log('Wiring the bower dependencies into the html');

  var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
  var options = config.getWiredepDefaultOptions();

  // Only include stubs if flag is enabled
  var js = args.stubs ? [].concat(config.js, config.stubsjs) : config.js;

  return gulp
    .src(config.index)
    .pipe(wiredep(options))
    .pipe(inject(js, '', config.jsOrder))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.client));
});

gulp.task('inject', ['wiredep', 'styles', 'templatecache'], function () {
  log('Wire up css into the html, after files are ready');

  return gulp
    .src(config.index)
    .pipe(inject(config.css))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.client));
});

/**
 * Run the spec runner
 * @return {Stream}
 */
gulp.task('serve-specs', ['build-specs'], function (done) {
  log('run the spec runner');
  serve(true /* isDev */, true /* specRunner */);
  done();
});

/**
 * Inject all the spec files into the specs.html
 * @return {Stream}
 */
gulp.task('build-specs', ['templatecache'], function (done) {
  log('building the spec runner');

  var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
  var templateCache = config.temp + config.templateCache.file;
  var options = config.getWiredepDefaultOptions();
  var specs = config.specs;

  if (args.startServers) {
    specs = [].concat(specs, config.serverIntegrationSpecs);
  }
  options.devDependencies = true;

  return gulp
    .src(config.specRunner)
    .pipe(wiredep(options))
    .pipe(inject(config.js, '', config.jsOrder))
    .pipe(inject(config.testlibraries, 'testlibraries'))
    .pipe(inject(config.specHelpers, 'spechelpers'))
    .pipe(inject(specs, 'specs', ['**/*']))
    .pipe(inject(templateCache, 'templates'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.client));
});

/**
 * Build everything
 * This is separate so we can run tests on
 * optimize before handling image or fonts
 */
gulp.task('build', ['optimize', 'images', 'fonts'], function () {
  log('Building everything');

  var msg = {
    title: 'gulp build',
    subtitle: 'Deployed to the build folder',
    message: 'Running `gulp serve-build`'
  };
  del(config.temp);
  log(msg);
  notify(msg);
});

/**
 * Optimize all files, move to a build folder,
 * and inject them into the new index.html
 * @return {Stream}
 */
gulp.task('optimize', ['inject', 'test'], function () {
  log('Optimizing the js, css, and html');

  var assets = $.useref.assets({ searchPath: './' });
  // Filters are named for the gulp-useref path
  var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css');
  var jsAppFilter = $.filter('**/' + config.optimized.app);
  var jslibFilter = $.filter('**/' + config.optimized.lib);

  var templateCache = config.temp + config.templateCache.file;

  return gulp
    .src(config.index)
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe(inject(templateCache, 'templates'))
    .pipe(assets) // Gather all assets from the html with useref
    // Get the css
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    .pipe($.minifyCss())
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
    // Get the custom javascript
    .pipe(jsAppFilter)
    .pipe($.ngAnnotate({ add: true }))
    .pipe($.uglify())
    .pipe(getHeader())
    .pipe(jsAppFilter.restore())
    // Get the vendor javascript
    .pipe(jslibFilter)
    .pipe($.uglify()) // another option is to override wiredep to use min files
    .pipe(jslibFilter.restore())
    // Take inventory of the file names for future rev numbers
    .pipe($.rev())
    // Apply the concat and file replacement with useref
    .pipe(assets.restore())
    .pipe($.useref())
    // Replace the file names in the html with rev numbers
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build));
});

/**
 * Remove all files from the build, temp, and reports folders
 * @param  {Function} done - callback when complete
 */
gulp.task('clean', function (done) {
  var delconfig = [].concat(config.build, config.temp, config.report);
  log('Cleaning: ' + $.util.colors.blue(delconfig));
  del(delconfig, done);
});

/**
 * Remove all fonts from the build folder
 * @param  {Function} done - callback when complete
 */
gulp.task('clean-fonts', function (done) {
  clean(config.build + 'fonts/**/*.*', done);
});

/**
 * Remove all images from the build folder
 * @param  {Function} done - callback when complete
 */
gulp.task('clean-images', function (done) {
  clean(config.build + 'images/**/*.*', done);
});

/**
 * Remove all styles from the build and temp folders
 * @param  {Function} done - callback when complete
 */
gulp.task('clean-styles', function (done) {
  var files = [].concat(
    config.temp + '**/*.css',
    config.build + 'styles/**/*.css'
  );
  clean(files, done);
});

/**
 * Remove all js and html from the build and temp folders
 * @param  {Function} done - callback when complete
 */
gulp.task('clean-code', function (done) {
  var files = [].concat(
    config.temp + '**/*.js',
    config.build + 'js/**/*.js',
    config.build + '**/*.html'
  );
  clean(files, done);
});

/**
 * Run specs once and exit
 * To start servers and run midway specs as well:
 *    gulp test --startServers
 * @return {Stream}
 */
gulp.task('test', ['vet', 'templatecache'], function (done) {
  startTests(true /*singleRun*/, done);
});

/**
 * Run specs and wait.
 * Watch for file changes and re-run tests on each change
 * To start servers and run midway specs as well:
 *    gulp autotest --startServers
 */
gulp.task('autotest', function (done) {
  startTests(false /*singleRun*/, done);
});

/**
 * serve the dev environment
 * --debug-brk or --debug
 * --nosync
 */
gulp.task('serve-dev', ['inject'], function () {
  serve(true /*isDev*/);
});

/**
 * serve the build environment
 * --debug-brk or --debug
 * --nosync
 */
gulp.task('serve-build', ['build'], function () {
  serve(false /*isDev*/);
});

/**
 * Bump the version
 * --type=pre will bump the prerelease version *.*.*-x
 * --type=patch or no flag will bump the patch version *.*.x
 * --type=minor will bump the minor version *.x.*
 * --type=major will bump the major version x.*.*
 * --version=1.2.3 will bump to a specific version and ignore other flags
 */
gulp.task('bump', function () {
  var msg = 'Bumping versions';
  var type = args.type;
  var version = args.ver;
  var options = {};
  if (version) {
    options.version = version;
    msg += ' to ' + version;
  } else {
    options.type = type;
    msg += ' for a ' + type;
  }
  log(msg);

  return gulp
    .src(config.packages)
    .pipe($.print())
    .pipe($.bump(options))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.root));
});

/**
 * Optimize the code and re-load browserSync
 */
gulp.task('browserSyncReload', ['optimize'], browserSync.reload);

////////////////

/**
 * When files change, log it
 * @param  {Object} event - event that fired
 */
function changeEvent(event) {
  var srcPattern = new RegExp('/.*(?=/' + config.source + ')/');
  log('File ' + event.path.replace(srcPattern, '') + ' ' + event.type);
}

/**
 * Delete all files in a given path
 * @param  {Array}   path - array of paths to delete
 * @param  {Function} done - callback when complete
 */
function clean(path, done) {
  log('Cleaning: ' + $.util.colors.blue(path));
  del(path, done);
}

/**
 * Inject files in a sorted sequence at a specified inject label
 * @param   {Array} src   glob pattern for source files
 * @param   {String} label   The label name
 * @param   {Array} order   glob pattern for sort order of the files
 * @returns {Stream}   The stream
 */
function inject(src, label, order) {
  var options = { read: false };
  if (label) {
    options.name = 'inject:' + label;
  }

  return $.inject(orderSrc(src, order), options);
}

/**
 * Order a stream
 * @param   {Stream} src   The gulp.src stream
 * @param   {Array} order Glob array pattern
 * @returns {Stream} The ordered stream
 */
function orderSrc(src, order) {
  //order = order || ['**/*'];
  return gulp
    .src(src)
    .pipe($.if(order, $.order(order)));
}

/**
 * serve the code
 * --debug-brk or --debug
 * --nosync
 * @param  {Boolean} isDev - dev or build mode
 * @param  {Boolean} specRunner - server spec runner html
 */
function serve(isDev, specRunner) {
  var debugMode = '--debug';
  var nodeOptions = getNodeOptions(isDev);

  nodeOptions.nodeArgs = [debugMode + '=5858'];

  if (args.verbose) {
    console.log(nodeOptions);
  }

  return $.nodemon(nodeOptions)
    .on('restart', ['vet'], function (ev) {
      log('*** nodemon restarted');
      log('files changed:\n' + ev);
      setTimeout(function () {
        browserSync.notify('reloading now ...');
        browserSync.reload({ stream: false });
      }, config.browserReloadDelay);
    })
    .on('start', function () {
      log('*** nodemon started');
      startBrowserSync(isDev, specRunner);
    })
    .on('crash', function () {
      log('*** nodemon crashed: script crashed for some reason');
    })
    .on('exit', function () {
      log('*** nodemon exited cleanly');
    });
}

function getNodeOptions(isDev) {
  return {
    script: config.nodeServer,
    delayTime: 1,
    env: {
      'PORT': port,
      'NODE_ENV': isDev ? 'dev' : 'build'
    },
    watch: [config.server]
  };
}

//function runNodeInspector() {
//    log('Running node-inspector.');
//    log('Browse to http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858');
//    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
//    exec('node-inspector');
//}

/**
 * Start BrowserSync
 * --nosync will avoid browserSync
 */
function startBrowserSync(isDev, specRunner) {
  if (args.nosync || browserSync.active) {
    return;
  }

  log('Starting BrowserSync on port ' + port);

  // If build: watches the files, builds, and restarts browser-sync.
  // If dev: watches less, compiles it to css, browser-sync handles reload
  if (isDev) {
    gulp.watch([config.less], ['styles'])
      .on('change', changeEvent);
  } else {
    gulp.watch([config.less, config.js, config.html], ['browserSyncReload'])
      .on('change', changeEvent);
  }

  var options = {
    proxy: 'localhost:' + port,
    port: 3000,
    files: isDev ? [
      config.client + '**/*.*',
      '!' + config.less,
      config.temp + '**/*.css'
    ] : [],
    ghostMode: { // these are the defaults t,f,t,t
      clicks: true,
      location: false,
      forms: true,
      scroll: true
    },
    injectChanges: true,
    logFileChanges: true,
    logLevel: 'info',
    logPrefix: 'hottowel',
    notify: true,
    reloadDelay: 0 //1000
  };
  if (specRunner) {
    options.startPath = config.specRunnerFile;
  }

  browserSync(options);
}

/**
 * Start Plato inspector and visualizer
 */
function startPlatoVisualizer(done) {
  log('Running Plato');

  var files = glob.sync(config.plato.js);
  var excludeFiles = /.*\.spec\.js/;
  var plato = require('plato');

  var options = {
    title: 'Plato Inspections Report',
    exclude: excludeFiles
  };
  var outputDir = config.report + '/plato';

  plato.inspect(files, outputDir, options, platoCompleted);

  function platoCompleted(report) {
    var overview = plato.getOverviewReport(report);
    if (args.verbose) {
      log(overview.summary);
    }
    if (done) { done(); }
  }
}

/**
 * Start the tests using karma.
 * @param  {boolean} singleRun - True means run once and end (CI), or keep running (dev)
 * @param  {Function} done - Callback to fire when karma is done
 * @return {undefined}
 */
function startTests(singleRun, done) {
  var child;
  var excludeFiles = [];
  var fork = require('child_process').fork;
  var Karma = require('karma').Server;
  var serverSpecs = config.serverIntegrationSpecs;

  if (args.startServers) {
    log('Starting servers');
    var savedEnv = process.env;
    savedEnv.NODE_ENV = 'dev';
    savedEnv.PORT = 8888;
    child = fork(config.nodeServer);
  } else {
    if (serverSpecs && serverSpecs.length) {
      excludeFiles = serverSpecs;
    }
  }

  new Karma({
    configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
    exclude: excludeFiles,
    singleRun: !!singleRun
  }, function () {
    done();
  }).start();

  ////////////////

  // function karmaCompleted(karmaResult) {
  //   log('Karma completed');
  //   if (child) {
  //     log('shutting down the child process');
  //     child.kill();
  //   }
  //   if (karmaResult === 1) {
  //     done('karma: tests failed with code ' + karmaResult);
  //   } else {
  //     done();
  //   }
  // }
}

/**
 * Formatter for bytediff to display the size changes after processing
 * @param  {Object} data - byte data
 * @return {String}      Difference in bytes, formatted
 */
function bytediffFormatter(data) {
  var difference = (data.savings > 0) ? ' smaller.' : ' larger.';
  return data.fileName + ' went from ' +
    (data.startSize / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' kB to ' +
    (data.endSize / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' kB and is ' +
    formatPercent(1 - data.percent, 2) + '%' + difference;
}

/**
 * Log an error message and emit the end of a task
 */
//function errorLogger(error) {
//    log('*** Start of Error ***');
//    log(error);
//    log('*** End of Error ***');
//    this.emit('end');
//}

/**
 * Format a number as a percentage
 * @param  {Number} num       Number to format as a percent
 * @param  {Number} precision Precision of the decimal
 * @return {String}           Formatted perentage
 */
function formatPercent(num, precision) {
  return (num * 100).toFixed(precision);
}

/**
 * Format and return the header for files
 * @return {String}           Formatted file header
 */
function getHeader() {
  var pkg = require('./package.json');
  var template = ['/**',
    ' * <%= pkg.name %> - <%= pkg.description %>',
    ' * @authors <%= pkg.authors %>',
    ' * @version v<%= pkg.version %>',
    ' * @link <%= pkg.homepage %>',
    ' * @license <%= pkg.license %>',
    ' */',
    ''
  ].join('\n');
  return $.header(template, {
    pkg: pkg
  });
}

/**
 * Log a message or series of messages using chalk's blue color.
 * Can pass in a string, object or array.
 */
function log(msg) {
  if (typeof (msg) === 'object') {
    for (var item in msg) {
      if (msg.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        $.util.log($.util.colors.blue(msg[item]));
      }
    }
  } else {
    $.util.log($.util.colors.blue(msg));
  }
}

/**
 * Show OS level notification using node-notifier
 */
function notify(options) {
  var notifier = require('node-notifier');
  var notifyOptions = {
    sound: 'Bottle',
    contentImage: path.join(__dirname, 'gulp.png'),
    icon: path.join(__dirname, 'gulp.png')
  };
  _.assign(notifyOptions, options);
  notifier.notify(notifyOptions);
}

module.exports = gulp;
```

**app.js**

```js
/*jshint node:true*/
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8001;
var four0four = require('./utils/404')();
var multer = require('multer');
var cors = require('cors');
var route = require('./routes')(io);

var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;

app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/favicon.ico'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '2mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  limit: '2mb',
  extended: true,
  parameterLimit: 50000
}));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use('/api', route);

mongoose.connect(
  'mongodb://localhost/hrisdb',
  { useMongoClient: true },
  function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Not connected to Remote Database' + err);
    } else {
      console.log('Successfully connected Remote Database');
    }
  });

console.log('connection', mongoose.connection.readyState);
console.log('About to crank up node');
console.log('PORT=' + port);
console.log('NODE_ENV=' + environment);

switch (environment) {
  case 'build':
    console.log('** BUILD **');
    app.use(express.static('./build/'));
    // Any invalid calls for templateUrls are under app/* and should return 404
    app.use('/app/*', function (req, res, next) {
      four0four.send404(req, res);
    });
    // Any deep link calls should return index.html
    app.use('/*', express.static('./build/index.html'));
    break;
  default:
    console.log('** DEV **');
    app.use(express.static('./src/client/'));
    app.use(express.static('./'));
    app.use(express.static('./tmp'));
    // Any invalid calls for templateUrls are under app/* and should return 404
    app.use('/app/*', function (req, res, next) {
      four0four.send404(req, res);
    });
    // Any deep link calls should return index.html
    app.use('/*', express.static('./src/client/index.html'));
    break;
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('connected:', socket.client.id);

  socket.on('serverEventAttendance', function (data) {
    console.log('this data', data);
    io.emit('socketAttendanceIn', data);
  });

  socket.on('serverEventAttendanceOut', function (data) {
    console.log('this data', data);
    io.emit('socketAttendanceIn', data);
  });
});

http.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
  console.log('env = ' + app.get('env') +
    '\n__dirname = ' + __dirname + '\nprocess.cwd = ' + process.cwd());
});
```

Comment: Where is the code referencing the template?

Comment: @Brian I've added the dashboard routes.